# ModelState validation error duplication in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-apicontroller

I use asp.net mvc5, api conrollers.

I'm try valid data

`[Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"\+?[0-9]{7,15}", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }`

And it work nice , but if I try send invalid data, server return me 2 errors

```
{
  "message": "The request is invalid.",
  "modelState": {
    "model.ParentPhoneNumber": [
      "Invalid Phone Number",
      "Invalid Phone Number"
    ]
  }
}
```

in controller

```
 public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Somemethod(SomeBindingModel model)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState); // **return 2 errors**
            }


        }
```

How I can fix this bug and have only one validation error?

Comment: what exactly looks the invalid data? Is this empty string?

Comment: No matter what validation. the regular expression, min/max  length,  etc. if model not valid   server return two errors, but must return one.

Comment: @VovaLeskiv, Debug the code and inspect the ModelState before it is return. back track to see if you have any action filters that may be adding the additional errors

Comment: @VovaLeskiv Did you found the problem ? I got the same problem with duplicate modelstate errors

Comment: @Emil No. It was a not critical problem.